# You attempted to import ../container/App which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

pls can anyone help as, I am a beginner in react

Comment: Replace .. by . at line import App

Comment: `./container/App`? because it looks like `index.js` is in the same folder as the container folder.

Comment: Thanx a lot .. My error resolved

Answer (score 0):

Typo error

Replace .. by . at line import App